# How to use Cycle / Swap tactics?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Consider the proof code:

```
Definition f (a: nat): nat.
Proof.
Admitted.



Lemma rew: forall (a p : nat) (A: a + 1 = p),
    f a = f p.
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma userew: forall (a b: nat), f a = f b.
Proof.
  intros.
  erewrite rew.
  cycle 1.
  (* Goal does not cycle *)
  swap 1 2.
  (* Goal does not swap *)
Abort.
```

Unfortunately, it seems that `cycle` and `swap` do not work. Why, and how do I use them correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the story is interesting and unintuitive.

A usage of : `tac; cycle` *does* work, because `; cycle` runs `cycle` on *all* goals, which cycles properly.

However, `tac. cycle` does not. Why?

The reason is that `tac.` is actually shorthand for "call the current [goal selector](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#goal-selectors), and then run `tac`".  The default goal selector is `Focus 1`.

This causes `cycle` to try to cycle a list of 1 goal,  (the focued goal), which does nothing.

However, in this model, `swap 1 2` should produce an error, because we try to swap `1` and `2` from a list of one goal. [I raised an issue about this on the `coq` bug tracker](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/7935)

The solution is to use `all: swap` or `all:cycle`. This focuses on all the goals first, which allows `swap` and `cycle` to work as expected.

Full code listing:

```
Definition f (a: nat): nat.
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma rew: forall (a p : nat) (A: a + 1 = p),
    f a = f p.
Proof.
Admitted.

Lemma userew: forall (a b: nat), f a = f b.
Proof.
  intros.
  erewrite rew.
  (* NOTICE all: *)
  all: cycle 1.
  (* NOTICE all: *)
  all: swap 1 2.
Abort.
```

**TL;DR** use `tactic; swap` or `all:swap`

Comment: In other words, `tac.` is a short-hand for `1: tac.`, unless you change the default goal selector.